# Наследование событий (events) в qt

Tags: c++, qt

Есть главное окно `QMainWindow`

- внутри есть классы виджетов, один из них это `QPushButton` ( при нажатии соединяется с `close()` )
- есть также обработчик событий который спрашивает при выходе

Борюсь с этой проблемой уже третий день
При выходе по кнопке "Выход" закрывается виджет. Как унаследовать событие закрытия главного окна?

> mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    virtual void closeEvent (QCloseEvent *event);
    StartWindow *startWindow;
};
```

> mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    startWindow = new StartWindow;
}
void MainWindow::closeEvent (QCloseEvent *event)
{
   //переопределила
}
```

> startwindow.h

```
class StartWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit StartWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
private slots:
    void slotQuit();
private:
    virtual void closeEvent (QCloseEvent *event);
};
```

> startwindow.cpp

```
StartWindow::StartWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    butQuit = new QPushButton(tr("Выход"));
    hLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    hLayout->addWidget(butQuit, 2);
    setLayout(hLayout);
    // соединение кнопок с слотами
    connect(butQuit, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotQuit()));
}

void StartWindow ::slotQuit()
{
    this -> close();
}
void StartWindow::closeEvent (QCloseEvent *event)
{
    // переопределила

}
```

В главном окне, должен меняться виджет при нажатии на кнопки, но при нажатии на Выход, закрывается сам виджет

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в Виджете, (который в главном окне) закрывалось главное окно?

Comment: Вы привели много кода, но проблему обрисовали не совсем чётко. Приведите минимальное количество кода, который воспроизводит Вашу проблему, а также чётко опишите, что Вы делаете, и что работает не так, как хочется.

Comment: @ixSci   В главном окне, должен меняться виджет при нажатии на кнопки, но при нажатии на Выход, закрывается сам виджет. При этом при Выходе из программы должен появится QMessange. Я переопределила событие CloseEvent для главного окна работает, а для виджета нет. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в Виджете, (который в главном окне) закрывалось главное окно?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно есть стандартные средства, но мне приходит идея реализовать сигнал у `StartWindow` и подписать на это событие `MainWindow`.

> startwindow.h

```
#ifndef STARTWINDOW_H
#define STARTWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QCloseEvent>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class StartWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit StartWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
signal:
    void closedWindow(QCloseEvent *event)
private slots:
    void slotQuit();
private:
    QPushButton *butQuit;
    QPushButton *butStart;
    QHBoxLayout *hLayout;

    virtual void closeEvent (QCloseEvent *event);
};

#endif // STARTWINDOW_H
```

> *.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    startWindow = new StartWindow;
    setCentralWidget(startWindow);
    connect(startWindow, &StartWindow::closedWindow,
            this, [this] (event) { closeEvent(event); });
}
void StartWindow::closeEvent (QCloseEvent *event) {
    // some code
    emit closedWindow(event);
}
```

Comment: @kto-to это не то что мне нужно